# Why can Object not be cast to generic of Object but can be cast to generic with wildcard?

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I have the following class:

```java
class Box<T> {
    public Box(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public T value;
}
```

Why can’t I do this:

```java
Object obj = new Object();
boolean isBox = obj instanceof Box<Object>;
```

```
|  Error:
|  java.lang.Object cannot be safely cast to Box<java.lang.Object>
|  boolean isBox = obj instanceof Box<Object>;
|                  ^-^
```

But I *can* do this:

```java
Object obj = new Object();
boolean isBox = obj instanceof Box<?>;
```